# (ROS) How to save a log file with a relative path?

Tags: c++, ros

I am using the command roslaunch to run a node.

```
roslaunch loop record_node
```

This node is located in

```
/home/user/Dropbox/Lab/lp_ws/src/loop/src/record.cpp
```

I want to use this node to save a log file to another directory in

```
/home/user/Dropbox/Lab/lp_ws/src/loop/plot/log.dat
```

So in the cpp file, I write

```
hand_x_record.open("../plot/hand_x.dat", ios::app);
```

However, it doesn't work. No file is saved. But it works when I use an absolut path. I check the current path with:

```
char current_absolute_path[100000];
if (NULL == realpath("./", current_absolute_path))
{
    printf("***Error***\n");
    exit(-1);
}
strcat(current_absolute_path, "/");
printf("current absolute path:%s\n", current_absolute_path);
```

The out put is

```
current absolute path:/home/user/.ros/
```

The roslaunch command takes me to the .ros/ directory.

How can I use a relative path to save the log by using roslaunch command?

Comment: Assuming your program IS writing */home/user/plot/hand_x.dat*, set the `cwd` attribute in the launch script. Details documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes

Comment: the location of the source file has nothing to do with the current directory of the process when the program is run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing to a path that is in a ROS package (based on your path I assume your package is called `loop`), you can use the ROS package interface for C++:

```
#include <ros/package.h>
std::string path = ros::package::getPath("loop");
```

Then you could append `/plot/log.dat` to this to get your full desired path. Alternatively, you can pass the file path in as a parameter when you start your node if your path is not relative to a ROS package. For example your node in the launch file can look like

```
<node name="my_node" pkg="loop" type="record">
    <param name="path" value="/home/user/Dropbox/Lab/lp_ws/src/loop/plot"/>
</node>
```

And then you can read it off as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Accessing_Private_Parameters).